# Nested IIF statement creation

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, I am trying to filter out trans.code where the trans.code is even and column 1 <> 2. I would like the query to skip rows that meet this condition, but keep everything else.

Comment: share ore details

Comment: Like: `WHERE trans.code % 2 = 0 AND [column 1] <> 2`? No reason for `IIf()` or `CASE` here, from the sounds of it.

Comment: Wouldn't that only select the rows where the trans.code is positive and the columns don't match? I am wanting to omit those rows.

Comment: @RDBCruzer `%` is the modulus operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

What you want is logically the same as:

```
WHERE trans.code is odd OR column 1 = 2
```

Comment: I think or (a.transaction_code  % 2 <> 0 and a.gl_date <> a.effective_date) may end up working for me. Thank you!